# Oracle-Making condition in effect according to subquery

Tags: oracle, select, subquery, constraints

How to modify as if a condition does not exist if the subquery returns NULL.
The expected result is;

```
EQUIP MODEL VAL K1 K2
----- ----- --- --- -- 
e1    m1    2   c1   5
e1    m1    1        6
```

but, of course, my code below returns null because of the condition with the subquery.

[Data Tables and data]

```
  CREATE TABLE WC_BASE  (  
      EQUIP VARCHAR2(15),
      MODEL VARCHAR2(15),
      VAL VARCHAR2(15),
      K1 VARCHAR2(15),
      K2 VARCHAR2(15)
      );
  CREATE TABLE M_IF  (  
      LOT VARCHAR2(15),
      ITEM1 VARCHAR2(15)
      );
  INSERT INTO WC_BASE VALUES('e1','m1','2','c1','5');  
  INSERT INTO WC_BASE VALUES('e1','m1','1',NULL,'6');  
  INSERT INTO M_IF VALUES('L1','c1');  
  INSERT INTO M_IF VALUES('L2','c2');  
  INSERT INTO M_IF VALUES('L4',NULL);
```

[My Code]

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM WC_BASE
 WHERE EQUIP ='e1'
 AND MODEL ='m1'
 --AND K1=(SELECT ITEM1 FROM M_IF WHERE LOT = 'L1'); --This returns result.
 AND K1=(SELECT ITEM1 FROM M_IF WHERE LOT = 'L4'); --How to modify as if this conditon does not exist if the subquery returns NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `JOIN` both tables and add a contion that matches when both values are `NULL`:

```
SELECT b.*, i.lot 
FROM wc_base b
INNER JOIN m_if i 
    ON i.item1 = b.k1 OR (i.item1 IS NULL AND b.k1 IS NULL)
WHERE b.equip ='e1' AND b.model ='m1'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=92cee0ec45a574e0743190c1d4e70af9)**:

```
EQUIP | MODEL | VAL | K1   | K2 | LOT
:---- | :---- | :-- | :--- | :- | :--
e1    | m1    | 2   | c1   | 5  | L1 
e1    | m1    | 1   | null | 6  | L4
```